# git: how to tell if a file or folder is committed versus ignored?

Tags: git

In Git, how do I tell if a file or folder is committed versus ignored?

That is, I have a folder in the current directory and I don't know if it's been committed, or, if there's a .gitignore somewhere that is ignoring the folder. When I do 'git status' the folder is not listed in any sections.

Secondly, if the folder has been committed, is there an easy way to tell which of its files are committed? For example:

```
folder contains:
- 0001.csv
- 0002.csv
- ...
- 2000.csv
```

And I want to list which files have been committed, and which have been ignored.

Comment: If you try to do `git add <one of those files>` it will tell you that it is ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
git status --ignored
```

?

That will show a result that looks like:

> Changes not staged for commit:
>     (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
>     (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)
>
> (all added / modified)
>
> Ignored files:
>     (use "git add -f ..." to include in what will be committed)
>
> (all ignored files)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `git status --ignored`